# raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)

Tags: python, json, loops, gzip

I am trying to load .json data dictionaries as follows:

```
import json
import gzip
filename = "tweets.json.txt.gz"
tweet = []
for line in gzip.open(filename , 'rt', encoding='utf-8'):
    tweet.append(json.loads(line.strip()))
```

but receive the following error:

```
File ... line 340, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)

JSONDecodeError: Extra data
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: How is the file organized?  The way you're using it, it would have to contain a complete json object on each separate line.  json files usually aren't arranged like that.

Comment: @JohnGordon You're right, this file is not arranged like that. The file is not organized in any way. No separate lines for objects. Should I separate the objects?

Comment: Try `tweets = json.load(gzip.open(filename , 'rt', encoding='utf-8'))`

Comment: @JohnGordon I am still getting the same error

Comment: So apparently the file isn't one json object per line, nor is it a single large json object.  It must be some custom format, so we can't help without actually seeing it.

Comment: Try printing out the a small number of the initial lines being read and adding them to your question — that way we can see the format of the data you're dealing with.